# firebase messaging() cause white screen in ios in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i just add `initializedFirebaseApp.messaging()` in my react js project , it's fine in both of web and android version, but in ios , there is white blank screen and my app doesn't load